# Is it better to use <article> or <li> tag for image grid with text

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to code a page like this:

[image]

It is a 4 x 4 layout grid with text. I started coding it using the article tag but got stuck when I tried to do the second row. Should the li tag be used instead?
Any suggestions greated appreciated.
Thanks

Below is the css & html:

```css
.product-col-one {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: #99BF38;
}
.product-col-two {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: #99BF38;
}
.product-col-three {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: #99BF38;
}
.product-col-four {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  background-color: #99BF38;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-col-one" style="position:relative; left:100px;  
     top:30px">
  <article>
    <div class="col-thumb">
      <img src="image/teddy04-175x140.jpg" width="175px" height="140px" alt "">
    </div>
    <!-- end col-thumb -->
    <h6>Henry Teddy Bear</h6>
  </article>
</div>
<!-- end product-col-one -->

<div class="product-col-two" style="position:relative; left:125px;    
      top:30px">
  <article>
    <div class="col-thumb">
      <img src="image/teddy03-175x140.jpg" width="175px" height="140px" alt "">
    </div>
    <!-- end col-thumb -->
    <h6>James Teddy Bear</h6>
  </article>
</div>
<!-- end product-col-two -->

<div class="product-col-three" style="position:relative; left:150px;
     top:30px">
  <article>
    <div class="col-thumb">
      <img src="image/teddy02-175x140.jpg" width="175px" height="140px" alt "">
    </div>
    <!-- end col-thumb -->
    <h6>Andrew Teddy Bear</h6>
  </article>
</div>
<!-- end product-col-three -->

<div class="product-col-four" style="position:relative; left:175px;  
      top:30px">
  <article>
    <div class="col-thumb">
      <img src="image/teddy175x140.jpg" width="175px" height="140px" alt "">
    </div>
    <!-- end col-thumb -->
    <h6>John Teddy Bear</h6>
  </article>
</div>
<!-- end product-col-four -->
```

Comment: `li` tag approach will be good in this case. `article` tag doesn't suits in this case.. also instead of using `h6` use `caption` tag.

Answer (score 3):

See the definition of [`<article>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element):

> The [`article`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element) element [represents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#represents) a complete, or
>   self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site
>   and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable,
>   e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or
>   newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an
>   interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of
>   content.

See the definition of [`<li>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element):

> The [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) element represents a list item. If its parent element is
>   an [`ol`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element), or [`ul`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element), then the element is an item of the parent
>   element's list, as defined for those elements. Otherwise, the list
>   item has no defined list-related relationship to any other [`li`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)
>   element.

Choose the better one depending on the semantic meaning of the elements in your site. For example

- If your site is some kind of a blog in which each day you post a photo of a teddy bear with a small text, `article` can be appropriate.
- If your site has a list of images of teddy bears that link to pages where people can buy them, `li` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Used the li element in the end, which was appropriate for what I was after

Answer (score 0):

I think `li` along with `<figure>` tag as `article` mean to be have some text content which represent some information. 
you must use `li` with `figure` tag and use `caption` instead of `h6`.